# Looking for a Client-Side integration solution integrating WEB application with Silverlight and VB6

Tags: javascript, windows, silverlight, client, integration

I am looking for  a client side integration solution/architecture. I need to integrate a asp.net web application (dynamics CRM) with other Silverlight and VB6 systems. the problem is how to activate EXE securely and with no popups and how to pass parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation I used a light weight ESB \ pub sub \    message queueing engine.

depending on perfomance requirements and maintabilty you can use either an engine for each node, or a central engine, where each queue or pub sub topic contains the node ID.

This is similar to the 'intent' concept in android.

Comment: Thanks, Ophir, That sounds like the solution we are currently testing. Can you recommend any framework for that solution ?

Comment: We used TIBCO EMS, as is was already used for other projects, and it was lightweight enough. For a new project I would take a closer look at zeromq.